# Why is CreateReadStream not firing error event?

Tags: node.js, csv, npm, node-csv-parse

I am attempting to do some error handling for a csv file. When changing the name of the file to something that does not exists,
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'testdat.csv'` is displayed but the on error event is not fired.

Here is the current implementation:

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('testdat.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('open', () => {
    })
    .on('headers', (headers) => {
        validateHeader(headers);
    })
    .on('data', (data) => {
        temp.push(data);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        validateData(temp);
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the error event handler before piping.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

var readable = fs.createReadStream('testdat.csv');

readable.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

// pipe function returns different stream
var writable = readable.pipe(csv())

writable.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I've had this issue for the past few hours, wish I'd found this thread sooner. Thanks!

Comment: hmm you'd think attaching things would be fine up until the stream is unpaused. Easy to miss this.